# Decrypt Password Generated by ASP.Net App in JSP App

Tags: jsp, encryption

I have switched an application from ASP.Net to JSP servlets.  In the old project all user passwords were encrypted and stored in a sql database.  Now I want to authenticate the users with the existing encrypted passwords, created by the old application, using the new application.

Is there is any way to decrypt that password in JSP and authenticate the user?

The programmer has not used a separate method to do the encryption.  He encrypted the password by using a built-in method.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inbuilt method"?

Comment: Inbuilt method means like password.encrypt(); method in ASP .NET

Answer (score 1):

You can take the User's password and encrypt it using the "inbuilt" method and match the output from the existing password in the database.

Comment: Now i am using the jsp-servlet.. How come the output of method used by the .NET programmer to encrypt the password will be the same as the output produced by method which i`ll used to encrypt the user entered password..

Comment: That's the point...I am saying that you should use the 'same' method as used by the other programmer to encrypt the password. Look it up in the source code of your previous project and port it exactly into your JSP/Servlet project.

Comment: Its a method from .Net how it can be same as the encryption method in JSP-Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first answer. You should keep in mind though that in this way you are vulnerable to collision attacks, because hash functions usually are not injective.

In any case, you shouldn't do the verification in JSP, better in the controller, because JSP pages are supposed to only provide the view.

Good luck and keep us updated with your progress!

Comment: 1) For decent cryptographic hash functions fining a collision is *hard* 2) Even if you get a collision, that's not a big problem for password hashing. To attack password hashing you need a preimage attack.

Comment: I agree that for good hash functions it should be hard to get a collision. However, we do not know exactly the hash function used in this example, so I was considering the general case. One could also use salt as an additional protection. It is also possible that this unknown function be broken via a brute force attack.